# How to solve asymptotic expansion: $\sqrt{1-2x+x^2+o(x^3)}$

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Determinate the best asymptotic expansion for $x \to 0$ for:

$$\sqrt{1-2x+x^2+o(x^3)}$$

How should I procede?
In other exercise I never had the $o(x^3)$ in the equation but was the maximum order to consider.

Comment: Shortcut, which may explain the *divine surprises* in the answers below: $1-2x+x^2=(1-x)^2$ hence one is looking at $$\sqrt{(1-x)^2+o(x^3)}=(1-x)\sqrt{1+\frac{o(x^3)}{(1-x)^2}}=(1-x)\sqrt{1+o(x^3)},$$ which is $$(1-x)(1+o(x^3))=1-x+o(x^3).$$

Comment: 1 minute. $ $ $ $

Comment: why $(1-x)^2$ and not $(x-1)^2$?

Comment: Hmm... well... because $(1-x)^2=(x-1)^2$ probably? :-) If your question is why the prefactor of the square root should be $(1-x)$ instead of $(x-1)$, note that this prefactor is a priori $|x-1|$ and that, when $x\to0$, $|x-1|=1-x$.

Comment: ok, but if I use $\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + o(x^3)}$ I get:

$$(x-1)(1+o(x^3) = x-1+o(x^3)$$

What am I missing?

Comment: No you do not get that. *Please read my previous comment*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall the Taylor series expansion, as $u \to 0$,
$$
\sqrt{1+u}=1+\frac{u}2-\frac{u^2}8+\frac{u^3}{16}+o(u^3).
$$ Setting, as $x \to 0$,
$$
u=-2x+x^2+o(x^3)
$$ it gives
$$
1+\frac{-2x+x^2+o(x^3)}2-\frac{(-2x+x^2+o(x^3))^2}8+\frac{(-2x)^3}{16}+o(x^3)
$$ or
$$
1+\frac{-2x+x^2}2-\frac{4x^2-4x^3}8+\frac{-8x^3}{16}+o(x^3)
$$thus, as $x \to 0$,

> $$
> \sqrt{1-2x+x^2+o(x^3)}=1-x+o(x^3).
> $$

Answer (score 1):

You have the following asymptotic expansion :

$$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{x^3}{16}+o(x^3)$$

So :

$$\sqrt{1-2x+x^2+o(x^3)}=1+\frac{-2x+x^2+o(x^3)}{2}-\frac{(-2x+x^2+o(x^3))^2}{8}+\frac{(-2x+x^2+o(x^3))^3}{16}+o((-2x+x^2+o(x^3))^3)\\=1+\frac{-2x+x^2}{2}-\frac{4x^2-4x^3+x^4}{8}+\frac{-8x^3+12x^4-6x^5+x^8}{16}+o(x^3)\\=1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{2}-\frac{x^3}{2}+o(x^3)=1-x+o(x^3)$$